# Can stories be "revived"?

Tags: creative-writing, editing

Has it happened to you that "you're in love" with an idea of yours? Like a core idea that you won't let go no matter what?

I heard that people usually write, check and recheck the story they write, putting much effort into polishing. But once it fails due to some reason, they move to another one. If I speak of a story as the current assembly of elements that the story have, then maybe the story it's dead there. But If I talk about the core idea that drives the story, not the way it is told, wouldn't it be different?

Can a story that was once presented to an editor, and rejected, be perfected in order to be presented to another editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. When an editor rejects a story, you can revise it and submit it somewhere else.

You can also submit it to another editor **without revising it**. Editors are human, and have individual tastes. And their slush readers are humans with individual tastes. One editor or reader may hate a story, and another love it.

Further, editors tastes differ from yours, which means that:

- An editor may love one of your stories that you don't think is very good.
- The things you do to "perfect" a story might make it less suitable for any given editor.

Rejection may not be entirely (or even largely) about the story. It's just a mismatch between the story and the editors tastes and needs **at that moment.**

So make the story as good as you know how. Don't worry about perfection. And try lots of editors.

Comment: I thought of that on one point, I'm still beginning, that's why I forgot it quickly. But you're right on that. I got many ideas shelved, to say it in a manner, many of them are very precious to me, that's why I don't like to think that idea is over, until I perfect my way of expressing it fully (the manuscript). Thanks for the answer. It was really helpful.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add: Revising is not the only way to revive a story. You can also throw out the old manuscript and write the story anew, given everything that you have since learned about how to write stories.

Comment: Now, that sounds very interesting. Didn't thought on that. Thanks =)